# Code runs okay on local Windows 2008 but can't create a subfolder in Application Data on Azure cloud

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, virtualization

My program needs to store stuff in "%AllUsersProfile%\Application Data\Stuff" (depends on code I can't change). I use the following code to recursively create a folder:

```
class DirCreator {
   internal static void Create( String path )
   {
       create( new DirectoryInfo( path ) );
   }
   void create( DirectoryInfo info )
   {
       String path = info.FullName;
       if( Directory.Exists( path ) ) {
           return;
       }
       if( info.Parent != null ) {
           create( info.Parent );
       }
       Directory.CreateDirectory( path );
   }
```

}

and the caller code does the following:

```
String appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData );
Creator.Create( Path.Combine( appData, "Application Data\\Stuff" ) );
```

I had to use that code ofter I discovered that simple `Directory.CreateDirectory()` wouldn't work.

Now on my local Windows 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit the code above works fine. When I do the same in my Azure role `OnStart()` the following happens:

- Environment.GetFolderPath() returns D:\ProgramData
- once recursion descends and calls `Directory.Exists( "D:\\ProgramData\\ApplicationData" )` that call returns `true` and recursion ends
- when later `Directory.CreateDirectory( "D:\\ProgramData\\Application Data\\Stuff" )` that call fails with

> Could not find a part of the path 'D:\ProgramData\Application Data\Stuff'.

which I just don't get. Maybe it's something with virtualization?

What is going on and how do I resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two little hints:

1. [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) already works recursively. No need for your `Creator` class. I suggest, you remove it.
2. Your combined path will be %AllUsersProfile%\Application Data\Application Data\Stuff. Note the double Application Data? `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` returns `%AllUsersProfile%\Application Data` which you combine with `Application Data\Stuff`...

Comment: I totally don't get why `Application Data` suddenly doubles - the string returned from `GetFolderPath()` is just `D:\ProgramData`. Anyway I removed the `Application Data` component from the path and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat surprised this works on a standard server... web sites under IIS run as a fairly limited privilege user, and I wouldn't expect that user to have the rights to create directories under %AllUsersProfile%. Are you sure when you're testing locally that the site isn't running under a higher-privileged account?

Comment: That code is inside `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()` override and that code runs under a rather priviledged account by default.

Comment: Code in OnStart runs as a normal (not admin) user by default, but if you set the executionPolicy="elevated", it will run as a local system user. Anyway, sounds like you sorted out the issue.